# How to calculate an average in Google Sheets excluding outliers which are manually specified in a separate column?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet containing a column with values, `Price/sqft`, which I would like to average, but only including values for which an adjacent column, `Outlier?` does not contain the word `yes`.

I took a stab at it following the [`AVERAGEIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256529?hl=en) documentation, but I'm getting a 'divide-by-zero' error:

[image]

Another way to do it would be to create a separate column which contains the conditional value and compute a regular `AVERAGE` on that. Is this the way to go? Or is there a way to do this in one go using `AVERAGEIF`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do use Averageif, you need to put the criterion range first and the average range last

```
=averageif(B2:B10,"<>Yes",A2:A10)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should use the formula `=AVERAGEIFS(Q5:Q13,S5:S13,"<>yes")`

Here, the syntax is like `AVERAGEIFS(average_range, criteria_range1, criterion1)`

[image: screenshot]

I hope this will be helpful.